# How to extract date from string of column of csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with named Version and with content-

```
Version
2024-01-02 rev. 003
2024-01-02 rev. 003
2023-11-17 rev. 003
```

how to get the data except greater date i.e 2024-01-02 rev. 003

I have tried by  not equal to maximum date, but null value is coming in dataframe

```
df3['Version'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Version'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors="coerce")

print("df3 version=======\n", df3['Version'])
df3 = df3[df3['Version'].ne(df3['Version'].max())]
print (df3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get datetimes in format `YYYY-MM-DD` first to helper `Series` and use it for filtering original `DataFrame`:

```
s = df3['Version'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', expand=False)
dates = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors="coerce")


df3 = df3[dates.ne(dates.max())]
print (df3)
               Version
2  2023-11-17 rev. 003
```

Comment: Empty dataframe is coming

Comment: @Priyatosh - Are datetime in format `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

Comment: @Priyatosh - test `print (dates)` if datetimes

Comment: yes its is in YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @Priyatosh - And `print (dates)` are datetimes?

Comment: date is also printing dates===========
 0   2024-01-02
1   2024-01-02

Comment: @Priyatosh can you provide `print(dates.describe(datetime_is_numeric=True))`?